Answers including AI generated code
I recently came across an answer whose author claimed they had used ChatGPT to create the Python code in their answer.
I find this objectionable; AI generated code is likely to miss the subtleties inherent in mathematics.
What is the correct course of action to take when one encounters answers that employ AI generated code?
